How to generate an output file with bazel that has the same name as a source file
There is a source file called package.json and for the release process (stamping) I want to modify the file to update the "version". So there is a run_binary target that would generate the output file.
run_binary(
    name = "a",
    outs = [
        "package.json",
    ],
    env = {
        "OUT_FILE": "$(location package.json)",
    },
    srcs = [
        "package.json",
    ],
    args = ["--dir", package_name()],
    tool = ":b",
    stamp = 1,
)

some_target(
    name = "c",
    srcs = [
        ...
        ":b",
    ],
    outs = ["d"],
    chdir = package_name(),
)

A later target depends on the package.json. The name of the files cannot be changed (as far as I can tell).
Bazel rules make it (for obvious reasons) difficult to generate output files with the same name as source files. So the "normal" approach of "src" and "out" to package.json leads to dependency errors.
Error in _run_binary: rule 'x' has file 'package.json' as both an input and an output

How can such a stamping to update the package.json file programmatically be done with Bazel?

There's no mechanism in bazel to distinguish between the input package.json and the output package.json. One way to approach this is if your release process outputs some package (zip, tar, installer, etc), you could name the output package_stamped.json (or similar) and have the packaging step rename it to package.json within the package.
